# SQL server after RAID problems

Tags: sql-server

We had a SQL server die due to some RAID problems.  We sent the machine out to a data recovery company and they are able to recover the .MDF and .LDF files from the drives.  Will I be able to use those files to restore the databases to a new machine?
What do I need to watch out for? Thanks!

Comment: With the `MDF` (main data file) and `LDF` (log data file), you *may* be able to attach the database to a new server: see the [MSDN manual page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) for a lot of info that you should read.

Comment: after attach, take a backup at every step... and then define a backup strategy because [raid is not a backup](http://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried out the old way of creating empty database with same name.
Stop sql server
Paste database at the same location ...
And restart the server ....
Does it helping u out .....
May be this article will give you more information.
http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/it-seems-our-sql-database-is-corrupted/

Answer (score 0):

unless they are not corrupted,You can use the files to restore databases.With out restoring you cant say about usability of those files..

If you are able to restore them with out any issues

1.First take backup of what you restored
2.Do a DBCC CHECKDB to check for any signs of data corruption

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! The issue has been resolved.